# My nginx site has too many active connections in waiting

Tags: nginx

nginx server has two 6-cores xeon cpu with HT feature.
So the whole system has 24 cpu-threads.

In nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 8;
worker_connections 4096;
```

nginx stub_status is:

```
Active connections: 3942 
server accepts handled requests
 142793 142793 505932 
Reading: 192 Writing: 36 Waiting: 3714
```

Too many requests stay in waiting queue, anything I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Waiting connections is not a problem in general. Nginx can handle many connections simultaneously。

If you don't like it, you may decrease it by tuning the `keepalive_timeout` directive.